# Adjust Makefile to only recompile files if they have changed

Tags: c, makefile

I have a question regarding my Makefile. The Makefile intends to compile C files containing code for a STM8 µC using the Cosmic compiler. The problem is that everytime I invoke the build target, all available source file  are getting recompiled without any change. I'm really new in the field of Makefiles and I have no idea how to fix it.

The second questions is related to the two targets "%.o: src/%.c" and %.o: src/stm8/%.c. They do exactly the same and I would prefer a generic one that is able to deal with all subdirectories within the src folder. With this solution it ist required to add an additional rule for each subfolder of the src folder

```
#***************PROJECT INFORMATIONS****************
PROJECT_NAME = stm8template
MODULES = stm8

#****************SET BUILD MODE*********************
ifeq ($(MODE), )
  MODE=Debug
endif

#***************DIRECTORY INFORMATION***************
SRCDIR = src
INCLUDES = includes
OUTPUT_DIR = bin/$(MODE)

#**************HELPER FUNCTIONS*********************
rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

#***************FILE SPECIFICATIONS***************
SOURCE_FILES = $(foreach d, $(call rwildcard,$(SRCDIR),*.c), $(notdir $d))
OBJECT_FILES = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCE_FILES))
HEADER_FILES = $(wildcard $(INCLUDES)/*.h) $(wildcard $(INCLUDES)/**/*.h)
INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM=$(foreach d, $(MODULES), -iincludes/$d) -iincludes -iC:\Hstm8

#***************COMPILER INFORMATIONS***************
CC = cxstm8
LIBS = -l +mods0
ifeq ("$(MODE)","Debug")
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM) -cl$(OUTPUT_DIR) -co$(OUTPUT_DIR) -pxp -no -pp +debug 
else
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM) -cl$(OUTPUT_DIR) -co$(OUTPUT_DIR) -pxp -no -pp
endif

#***************LINKER INFORMATIONS***************
LINKFILE=$(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(PROJECT_NAME).lkf
OUTFILE=$(PROJECT_NAME)
LFLAGS = -lC:\Lib

#*************FLASHER CONFIGURATIONS***************
FLASHER_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\st_toolset\stvp\STVP_CmdLine.exe"
DEVICE=STM8S105x6
PORT=USB
PROG_MODE=SWIM
BOARD_NAME=ST-LINK
FLASHER_PARAM = -no_loop

#***************BUILT TARGETS***************
all: build run

%.o: src/%.c
  $(info ********** Compile $< ***********)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $<

%.o: src/stm8/%.c
  $(info ********** Compile $< ***********)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $<

build: $(OBJECT_FILES)
  $(info ********** Build the Application ***********)
  clnk -m $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).map -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8 $(LINKFILE)
  cvdwarf $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8 
  chex -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).s19 $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8

run:
  $(info ********** Flashing the Application ***********)
  $(FLASHER_PATH) -BoardName=$(BOARD_NAME) -Device=$(DEVICE) -Port=$(PORT) -ProgMode=$(PROG_MODE) -FileProg="$(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).s19" $(FLASHER_PARAM)
```

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `DEVICE=STM8S105x6`  Using the '=' results in the macro being re-evaluated every time `DEVICE` is reference.  (usually) much better to use ':=' so the macro is only evaluated once

Comment: OT: before the `all` target, there should be a statement similar to: `.PHONY : all run build

Comment: regarding: `LFLAGS = -lC:\Lib`  The lower case 'l' is for selecting specific library names.  A upper case 'L' is for setting the path to the library files

Comment: regarding: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $<` (both occurrences)  The '$(LIBS) should NOT be in the compile statement.  Also `CFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM) -cl$(OUTPUT_DIR) -co$(OUTPUT_DIR) -pxp -no -pp` should include a '-c' option so that those compile statements do not try to link

Comment: suggest replacing: `%.o: src/%.c
  $(info ********** Compile $< ***********)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $<` with: `%.o: %.c $(INCLUDES)
  $(info ********** Compile $< ***********)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< $(INCLUDES)

Comment: suggest breaking this statement: `$(FLASHER_PATH) -BoardName=$(BOARD_NAME) -Device=$(DEVICE) -Port=$(PORT) -ProgMode=$(PROG_MODE) -FileProg="$(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).s19" $(FLASHER_PARAM)` into multiple lines, where each line is ended with a '\'

Comment: regarding: ifeq ("$(MODE)","Debug") CFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM) -cl$(OUTPUT_DIR) -co$(OUTPUT_DIR) -pxp -no -pp +debug else CFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM) -cl$(OUTPUT_DIR) -co$(OUTPUT_DIR) -pxp -no -pp endif would be much better written as: CFLAGS = -c $(INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM) -cl$(OUTPUT_DIR) -co$(OUTPUT_DIR) -pxp -no -pp $(MODE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `build` target never gets created, so the commands after it are executed every time you run `make` (or `make all` or `make build`), so the program is linked each time.

Change your `build` target so that it is phony:

```
.PHONY: build clean
```

and so that it depends on the program, not the object files:

```
build: $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8
```

and then have a rule (recipe) that builds the program if the object files are more recent:

```
$(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(info ********** Build the Application ***********)
    clnk -m $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).map -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8 $(LINKFILE)
    cvdwarf $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8 
    chex -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).s19 $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8
```

It isn't 100% clear to me that I chose the correct suffix for the program.  I would also create series of macros to avoid the repetition I see:

```
OUTFILE.sm8 = $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8
OUTFILE.s19 = $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).s19
OUTFILE.map = $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).map

build: $(OUTFILE.sm8)

$(OUTFILE.sm8): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(info ********** Build the Application ***********)
    clnk -m $(OUTFILE.map) -o $(OUTFILE.sm8) $(LINKFILE)
    cvdwarf $(OUTFILE.sm8) 
    chex -o $(OUTFILE.s19) $(OUTFILE.sm8)
```

Also, since I work on Unix mostly, I'd use `/` instead of `\`, but that's a minor detail.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added/changed the points you mentioned. But the problem still remains. Every time I invoke the build target, all object files are created regardless of any change occured. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Succinctly, No.  I don't have the energy to try setting up a simulation of your setup on my Mac.  Sorry that it wasn't a sufficient answer.  I don't normally use multi-directory builds — object files go into the source directory, not into stray other directories — so I haven't got a list of things that go wrong memorized (or, the list is "everything goes wrong so I don't do it any more", and haven't for the last 30+ years; but that also means I don't take advantage of the constructs you're using, such as wildcards, pattern substitutions and foreach, etc, basically because I don't trust them).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Thank you all for your help. I changed the Makefile in the way shown below. The second problem is now fixed but the first problem still remains.

Every time the build rule is invoked all .c files are recompiled. Compiling only the changed files is the main purpose/benefit of using make, I thought. So something is wrong but unfortunately I don't find the mistake.

```
#***************PROJECT INFORMATIONS****************
PROJECT_NAME = stm8template
MODULES = stm8

#****************SET BUILD MODE*********************
ifeq ($(MODE), )
    MODE=Debug
endif

#***************DIRECTORY INFORMATION***************
SRCDIR = src
INCLUDES = includes

#**************HELPER FUNCTIONS*********************
rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

#***************FILE SPECIFICATIONS***************
SOURCE_FILES = $(foreach d, $(call rwildcard,$(SRCDIR),*.c), $(notdir $d))
OBJECT_FILES = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(call rwildcard,$(SRCDIR),*.c))
HEADER_FILES = $(wildcard $(INCLUDES)/*.h) $(wildcard $(INCLUDES)/**/*.h)
INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM=$(foreach d, $(MODULES), -iincludes/$d) -iincludes -iC:\Hstm8

#***************COMPILER INFORMATIONS***************
CC = cxstm8
LIBS = -l +mods0
ifeq ("$(MODE)","Debug")
  CFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM) -cl$(OUTPUT_DIR) -co$(OUTPUT_DIR) -pxp -no -pp +debug 
else
  CFLAGS = $(INCLUDE_DIRS_PARAM) -cl$(OUTPUT_DIR) -co$(OUTPUT_DIR) -pxp -no -pp
endif

#***************LINKER INFORMATIONS***************
LINKFILE=$(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(PROJECT_NAME).lkf
LFLAGS = -LC:\Lib

#*******************OUTPUT FILES********************
OUTPUT_DIR = bin/$(MODE)
OUTFILE=$(PROJECT_NAME)
OUTFILE.sm8 = $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).sm8
OUTFILE.s19 = $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).s19
OUTFILE.map = $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).map
TARGET_FILE=$(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(PROJECT_NAME).elf

#*************FLASHER CONFIGURATIONS***************
FLASHER_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\st_toolset\stvp\STVP_CmdLine.exe"
DEVICE := STM8S105x6
PORT=USB
PROG_MODE=SWIM
BOARD_NAME=ST-LINK
FLASHER_PARAM = -no_loop

#***************BUILT TARGETS***************
.PHONY: all run build clean
all: build run

%.o: %.c
  $(info ********** Compile $< ***********)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $<

build: $(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(PROJECT_NAME).elf

$(TARGET_FILE): $(OBJECT_FILES)
  $(info ********** Build the Application ***********)
  clnk -m $(OUTFILE.map) -o $(OUTFILE.sm8) $(LINKFILE)
  cvdwarf $(OUTFILE.sm8) 
  chex -o $(OUTFILE.s19) $(OUTFILE.sm8)

run:
  $(info ********** Flashing the Application ***********)
  $(FLASHER_PATH) -BoardName=$(BOARD_NAME) -Device=$(DEVICE) -Port=$(PORT) -ProgMode=$(PROG_MODE) -FileProg="$(OUTPUT_DIR)\$(OUTFILE).s19" $(FLASHER_PARAM)
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is somewhere else. Somebody is messing with the timestamps. Try making just one object file (`make foo.o`) twice in a row. Does the second invocation still recompile it?

Comment: I tried it and even if I just call make with a single object file, the file is recompiled every time. If I change the output directory to create the object files in the src directory, everything is working. So it looks like the rule %.o : %.c is always looking for the corresponding .o file in the src directory. Because there is none (they are in the bin directory), the files get recreated